# Throgh coding how to know the app opened in web or app

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx

In SPFx solution how to know the whether the app opened in teams web app or desktop app
based on that i have to change the coding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (in case you have SPFx web part):

`this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.hostClientType`

Comment: getting the error Cannot read property 'sdks' of undefined

Comment: @BharatiSeelam Where did you put this line? It is supposed to be put inside the spfx web part (in the web part class, there is "context" member). Like, if you use yeoman generator, you should put that in HelloWorldWebPart class. i.e. "this" should be teh web part (in case of the HelloWorld, it is in the HelloWorldWebPart.ts file)

Comment: @Nikolay - used this in the properties of the web part as you mentioned above now its working fine.But facing the issue thoughif(this.props.teamsContext.hostClientType=="web")
    {
      window.open("https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/l/chat/0/0?users=" + userID + "&topicname=Chat",'', 'height=300,width=650');
    }
    else if(this.props.teamsContext.hostClientType=="desktop"){
      window.open('MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=' + userID);
    } i have given like above if it is a desktop thne also its trying to open the web action as well its opening the web action as well as the desktop